# subversion connection with local IP (192.168.x.y) connection failed

Tags: linux, svn, tcp

I'm subversion beginner user and I have created a server on my raspberry pi.
And the service is running.

I would like to checkout, commit, ... but I'm trying to commit with this syntax:

```
svn checkout 192.168.2.18/repository

svn checkout snv://192.168.2.18/repository
```

so the response is:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://192.168.2.18/repository'
```

I'm thinking that I don't use the good syntax. 
Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: in your post you wrote `snv://` instead of `svn://...`. However it may also be `http://` or `https://`. Have you tried ?

Comment: Thanks for your corrections and your help. 
I have tried http:// and https:// and the result is same.

Comment: Have you tried to ping at `192.168.2.18` ? Are there any repository files in `repository` folder ?